# Directional derivative identity

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ where $U$ is an open set, $p,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $v \neq \vec{0}$. Let's recall the definition of the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction of $v$:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(p) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(p+tv)-f(p)}{t}
$$
Taking in consideration a norm (euclidean for example) in our vector space over the reals ($\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R},|.|_e$), how can I prove the following identity?
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(p) = |v|_e\frac{\partial f}{\partial\frac{v}{|v|_e}}(p)
$$
I tried to use the formal ($\epsilon, \delta$) definition of limit but couldn't get much further.

Any kind of advice is going to be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggle I can see why this is true... It's just a simple substitution in the limit variable...
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(p) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(p+t v)-f(p)}{t} =  \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(p+t \frac{|v|}{|v|}v)-f(p)}{t}=
$$
now let $t' = t|v|$, therefore
$$
=\lim_{t'\rightarrow0}\frac{f(p+t'\frac{v}{|v|})-f(p)}{\frac{t'}{|v|}} = |v|\lim_{t'\rightarrow0}\frac{f(p+t'\frac{v}{|v|})-f(p)}{t'} = |v|\frac{\partial f}{\partial \frac{v}{|v|}}(p) 
$$